# Reparametrization in tensorflow-probability: tf.GradientTape() doesn't calculate the gradient with respect to a distribution's mean

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-probability

In `tensorflow` version `2.0.0-beta1`, I am trying to implement a `keras` layer which has weights sampled from a normal random distribution. I would like to have the mean of the distribution as trainable parameter.

Thanks to the "reparametrization trick" already implemented in `tensorflow-probability`, the calculation of the gradient with respect to the mean of the distribution should be possible in principle, if I am not mistaken.

However, when I try to calculate the gradient of the network output with respect to the mean value variable using `tf.GradientTape()`, the returned gradient is `None`.

I created two minimal examples, one of a layer with deterministic weights and one of a layer with random weights. The gradients of the deterministic layer's gradients are calculated as expected, but the gradients are `None` in case of the random layer. There is no error message giving details on why the gradient is `None`, and I am kind of stuck.

**Minimal example code:**

A: Here is the minimal example for the deterministic network:

```
import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer,Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import RandomNormal
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

import numpy as np

# example data
x_data = np.random.rand(99,3).astype(np.float32)

# # A: DETERMINISTIC MODEL

# 1 Define Layer

class deterministic_test_layer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(deterministic_test_layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(deterministic_test_layer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

# 2 Create model and calculate gradient

x = Input(shape=(3,))
fx = deterministic_test_layer(1)(x)
deterministic_test_model = Model(name='test_deterministic',inputs=[x], outputs=[fx])

print('\n\n\nCalculating gradients for deterministic model: ')

for x_now in np.split(x_data,3):
#     print(x_now.shape)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        fx_now = deterministic_test_model(x_now)
        grads = tape.gradient(
            fx_now,
            deterministic_test_model.trainable_variables,
        )
        print('\n',grads,'\n')

print(deterministic_test_model.summary())
```

B: The following example is very similar, but instead of deterministic weights I tried to use randomly sampled weights (randomly sampled at `call()` time!) for the test layer:

```
# # B: RANDOM MODEL

# 1 Define Layer

class random_test_layer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(random_test_layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.mean_W = self.add_weight('mean_W',
                                      initializer=RandomNormal(mean=0.5,stddev=0.1),
                                      trainable=True)

        self.kernel_dist = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=self.mean_W,scale_diag=(1.,))
        super(random_test_layer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        sampled_kernel = self.kernel_dist.sample(sample_shape=x.shape[1])
        return K.dot(x, sampled_kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

# 2 Create model and calculate gradient

x = Input(shape=(3,))
fx = random_test_layer(1)(x)
random_test_model = Model(name='test_random',inputs=[x], outputs=[fx])

print('\n\n\nCalculating gradients for random model: ')

for x_now in np.split(x_data,3):
#     print(x_now.shape)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        fx_now = random_test_model(x_now)
        grads = tape.gradient(
            fx_now,
            random_test_model.trainable_variables,
        )
        print('\n',grads,'\n')

print(random_test_model.summary())
```

**Expected/Actual Output:**

A: The deterministic network works as expected, and the gradients are calculated. The output is:

```
2.0.0-beta1



Calculating gradients for deterministic model: 

 [<tf.Tensor: id=26, shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[17.79845  ],
       [15.764006 ],
       [14.4183035]], dtype=float32)>] 


 [<tf.Tensor: id=34, shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[16.22232 ],
       [17.09122 ],
       [16.195663]], dtype=float32)>] 


 [<tf.Tensor: id=42, shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[16.382954],
       [16.074356],
       [17.718027]], dtype=float32)>] 

Model: "test_deterministic"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
deterministic_test_layer (de (None, 1)                 3         
=================================================================
Total params: 3
Trainable params: 3
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

B: However, in case of the similar random network, the gradients are not calculated as expected (using the reparametsization trick). Instead, they are `None`. The full output is

```
Calculating gradients for random model: 

 [None] 


 [None] 


 [None] 

Model: "test_random"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
random_test_layer (random_te (None, 1)                 1         
=================================================================
Total params: 1
Trainable params: 1
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Can anybody point me at the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/MultivariateNormalDiag) is not differentiable with respect to its input parameters (e.g. `loc`). In this particular case, the following would be equivalent:

```
class random_test_layer(Layer):
    ...

    def build(self, input_shape):
        ...
        self.kernel_dist = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=0, scale_diag=(1.,))
        super(random_test_layer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        sampled_kernel = self.kernel_dist.sample(sample_shape=x.shape[1]) + self.mean_W
        return K.dot(x, sampled_kernel)
```

In this case, however, the loss is differentiable with respect to `self.mean_W`.

**Be careful:** Although this approach might work for your purposes, note that calling the density function `self.kernel_dist.prob` would yield different results, since we took `loc` outside.

Comment: Thank you! I think what you did is that you explicitly implemented the reparametrization trick (see e.g. http://stillbreeze.github.io/REINFORCE-vs-Reparameterization-trick/), correct? I thought that the distribution objects in `tfp.distributions` should take care of the reparametrization themselves, which is why I am still a little bit confused. Is this maybe something that was changed from `tf 1` to `tf 2`?

Comment: Exactly, I explicitly implemented the reparametrization trick. Regarding the second question, to be honest, I don't know.

Comment: If you construct the MVNDiag within the `call` function, I think you should get gradients. We are working our way through the distributions to defer converting `Variable` to `Tensor`, which many distributions do in the constructor. As of today, instead of MVNDiag you could use `tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc=0, scale=the_weight), reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)` since `Normal` has already been fixed.